# PHP Session Security

Tags: php, session

I'm pretty new to PHP and I have been using $_SESSION to store active user details. However I have been told by a couple of people this is unsafe. Is this true?

I normally store the following in the PHP Session:

- LoggedIn
- UserID
- Username
- Email
- Forename
- Surname

If this is unsafe, what other methods are there that are secure?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php and be sure to follow the topmost link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're unsafe depending on the type of storage.

A secure method would be to use custom session handlers (via [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)) and store the information "somewhere safe" (i.e. not as session files in the globally readable `/tmp` directory).

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If you are on shared hosting and also you are running the default file session handler then it might be that someone else can read them. That's the only risk I am aware of. However, shared hosts that are configured like this are better be avoided because then users can read everything else you have, like database configuration and consequently steal your db...